# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when creating h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, ejb

I am try to create a h:selectOneMenu

I have been getting a number of errors but the latest one is in the subject line.  I have been working on this for some time but I have not been able to get it to work.

Please help

JPA:

```
package com.homework.jpa

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the GRIDMASTER database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Gridmaster.findAll", query="SELECT g FROM Gridmaster g")
public class Gridmaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long gridid;

    @Column(name="\"PROGRAM\"")
    private String program;

    public Gridmaster() {
    }

    public long getGridid() {
        return this.gridid;
    }

    public void setGridid(long gridid) {
        this.gridid = gridid;
    }


    public String getProgram() {
        return this.program;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }
}
```

EJB:

```
import com.homework.jpa.*;

import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class GridMasterBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

        public List<Gridmaster> getDisplayGridList() {
            return em.createQuery("FROM Gridmaster m", Gridmaster.class).getResultList();
}
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class gridMaster_backing {
    private static final String String = null;
    @EJB
    private GridMasterBean ejb;
    private List gridList = new ArrayList();    
    public String pickedGrid;

    public String getPickedGrid() {
        return pickedGrid;
    }

    public void setPickedgrid(String pickedGrid) {
        this.pickedGrid = pickedGrid;
    }

    public void setGridList(List gridList) {
        this.gridList = gridList;
    }

    public List getGridList() {
        // produces List of Grids
        gridList.clear();
        List gridList = ejb.getDisplayGridList();
            Iterator it  = gridList.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                 Gridmaster programCodes  = (Gridmaster)it.next();
                 SelectItem sItem = new SelectItem();
                 //Long GridId = Gridmaster.getGridid();

                 //String progName = programCodes.getDescription() + " -- " + programCodes.getProgramCode();
                 sItem.setLabel(program);
                 sItem.setValue(gridid);
                 gridList.add(sItem);
             }          
        return gridList; 
        }
    }
```

xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{gridMaster_backing.pickedGrid}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{gridMaster_backing.gridList}" />

        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  gridList.add(sItem). You are trying to add to the list while iterating over it.   Instead iterate of the list using index. Then add at index. Be sure to update  the iterator variable accordingly when you add at index.

Comment: Thanks Dan but I am not following your recommendation... I am not sure how I should change it with index.. can you provide an example?

Comment: Hint: [`ListIterator it = gridList.listIterator();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E))

Comment: What are you trying to do. Looks like you are creating a gridList=ejb.getDisplayGridList(). Then you are iterator over  that list and adding to the same list.  Is that your intention?

Comment: I am trying to create a drop down list with all the program codes in the table

Comment: I thought I would need to integrate through the result list to do this.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I do not need to iterate the List.  Thanks for the help